# Finding a set of representatives to an equivalence relation on sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, set-theory, equivalence-relations

1. Define an equivalence relation on the set of infinite real sequences by: a~b iff a-b is bounded. For example, the equivalence class of 0 (the constant sequence 0,0,0,...) is the set of all bounded sequences; the class of n (i.e. 1,2,3,...) is the set of all sequences of the form "n + a bounded sequence" and so on. I wonder if there is a way to write a set of representatives to this relation (i.e. a set that consists of exactly one sequence from each class)? I know there are infinitely many classes (e.g. [n],[2n],[3n],... but also [n^2],[n^3],[ln(n)],...) and I know (by the axiom of choice) there exists a set of representatives, but I don't know if there is a way to build/describe such a set. I hope my question is clear. (I couldn't think of any way to build such a set and I'm not sure it's possible).
2. Same question but for the relation "a-b is convergent".
3. Same question but for the relation "a-b converges to 0". (I did notice that if I define this relation only on the set of *convergent* sequences then I have a way to describe a set of representatives- one for each limit).

I feel like the answer is negative for all of my 3 questions but I want to make sure and also hear your thoughts.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think you can give an "explicit" description. It seems closely related to the "Bounding Number" which is undecidable in ZFC.You have 1 vote to Close. I gave you a +1.

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know about the bounding number, I read a little now (about "Cichoń's diagram"). In my case (because I took real sequences) I know the cardinality of a set of representatives is the cardinality of the continuum (e.g. because of [r*n] for every real r). But it "makes sense", I guess, that an explicit description will lead to finding the bounding (or dominating) number (which is about natural sequences).

Comment: (Also, I'm kinda new here so I don't think I understand the sentence "You have 1 vote to Close. I gave you a +1")

Comment: Somebody else voted to close (cancel) your Q. I gave it a positive vote.